# BDD and functional tests

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking, bdd

I am starting to buy into BDD. Basically, as I understand it, you write scenario that describes well acceptance criteria for certain story. You start by simple tests, from the outside-in, using mocks in place of classes you do not implement as yet. As you progress, you should replace mocks with real classes. From [Introduction to BDD](http://blog.dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/):

> At first, the fragments are
>   implemented using mocks to set an
>   account to be in credit or a card to
>   be valid. These form the starting
>   points for implementing behaviour. As
>   you implement the application, the
>   givens and outcomes are changed to use
>   the actual classes you have
>   implemented, so that by the time the
>   scenario is completed, they have
>   become proper end-to-end functional
>   tests.

My question is: When you finish implementing a scenario, should all classes you use be real, like in integration tests? For example, if you use DB, should your code write to a real (but lightweight in-memory) DB? In the end, should you have any mocks in your end-to-end tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it depends :-) As I understand, the tests produced by BDD are still unit tests, so you should use mocks to eliminate dependency on external factors like DB.

In full fledged integration / functionality tests, however, you should obviously test against the whole production system, without any mocks.

Answer (score 2):

Integration tests might contain stubs/mocks to fake the code/components outside the modules that you are integrating.

However, IMHO the end-to-end test should mean no stubs/mocks along the way but production code only. Or in other words - if mocks are present - it is not really end-to-end test.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by the time a scenario runs, ideally all your classes will be real. A scenario exercises the behaviour from a user's point of view, so the system should be as a user would see it.

In the early days of BDD we used to start with mocks in the scenarios. I don't bother with this any more, because it's a lot of work to keep mocking as you go down the levels. Instead I will sometimes do things like hard-code data or behaviour if it lets me get feedback from the stakeholders more quickly.

We still keep mocks in the unit tests though.

For things like databases, sure, you can use an in-memory DB or whatever helps you get feedback faster. At some point you should probably run your scenarios on a system that's as close to production as possible. If this is too slow, you might do it overnight instead of as part of your regular build cycle.

As for what you "should" do, writing the right code is far more tricky than writing the code right. I worry about using my scenarios to get feedback from the stakeholders and users before I worry about how close my environment is to a production environment. When you get to the point where changes are deployed every couple of weeks, sure, then you probably want more certainty that you're not introducing any bugs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter and ratkok.  I think you keep the mocks forever, so you always have unit tests.

Separately, it is appropriate to additionally have integration tests (no mocks, use a DB, etc. etc.).

You may even find in-betweens helpful at times (mock one piece of depended-on code (DOC), but not another).

Answer (score 0):

I've only recently been looking into BDD and in particular jBehave. I work in fairly large enterprises with a lot of waterfall, ceremony orientated people. I'm looking at BDD as a way to take the businesses use cases and turn then directly into tests which the developer can then turn into either unit test or integration tests.

BDD seems to me to be not just a way to help drive the developers understanding of what the business wants, but also a way to ensure as much a spossible that those requirements are accurately represented.

My view that if you are dealing with mocks then you are doing unit tests. You need both unit testing to test out the details of a classes operation, and integrations to test out that the class plays well with others. I find developers often get infused between the two, but it's best to be as clear as possible and keep there separate from each other.